# Does the Pi 4 resolve the Ethernet+USB bottleneck issue of past versions?

Tags: usb, ethernet-port, pi-4

The Pi 3 (and [previous models](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/44433/968)) had an [issue of bottlenecked bandwidth](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45131/968) when using Ethernet and USB simultaneously. Is this resolved in the Pi 4?

Comment: Forgive the MB/Mb mistake: https://twitter.com/ben_nuttall/status/1143037993957187584

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, it resolves it.

“While Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ added Gigabit Ethernet connectivity, throughput on Raspberry Pi 4 is free from the single shared USB 2.0 channel to the SoC.” (https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/raspberry-pi-4-specs-benchmarks/)

[image: Graph showing problem resolved]

Comment: To be more specific, the USB host controller is connected directly to the SoC via a PCIe bus. The Ethernet Controller is built directly in to the SoC.

Comment: rejoice! Though I suppose it would be nice if there was a PCIe built into the board for utilization.